# Is there a way to create an Android app that looks and behaves just like the homescreen of the same device?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need a home screen clone app that uses apps, folders, swipable screens of more apps and so on.

So far, I have looked into custom launchers like this one here: https://www.androidauthority.com/make-a-custom-android-launcher-837342-837342/

But to achieve what I need will require a lot of extra additions (the icons are easy enough, but I'll need folders and swiping as well).

Another approach I wondered about is Kiosk mode/Lock-Task-Mode and multi-app kiosk mode. I've looked at the docs and wondered if this could be used to harness the actual homescreen, while still executing code in the background based on what apps the user selects (ultimately acheiving the same desired effect of my project).

I've spent a full day looking at this but I want to know if I'm on the right path. Obviously, I could create an app that contains all of this, but I do think I want it to be a launcher app that's locked in place so that users can't operate the actual home screen and its apps. No malicious intent here, it's just for a closed-off research project.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that you want to create an app that, when started, reads out the home screen configuration of the current phone and displays it to the user and when you swipe to other home screens or open folders and start apps. Should this work for any home screen? When I hit the home button, shall your app be opened? Should your app also mimic the behavior when I swipe down/up from screen borders?

Comment: More or less. It doesn't have to be the exact home screen. I can probably leave out dragging, deleting apps, etc. Swiping yes. Starting apps I've worked out how to do, but that's actually less important as I want to be showing custom screens when other 'apps' are selected. Folders would be good and I am looking into that now, but mimicking the functionality of the OS seems like it could be a lot of work. It only needs to be like the home screen of a tablet I'm building for, compatability shouldn't be a big deal. Yes, and I've got the home button working. Up and down swiping isn't  required